# What is sitting inside LED array so that I can create my own drivers?

Tags: led, led-driver, led-matrix, mobile

I have a LED array and an app to drive it:

- https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id1431362600?mt=8
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yskj.led&hl=en_US

I connect to WiFi and I'm able to upload an image or some text to the thing.

I would like to write some clever software that runs on Raspberry Pi (or similar) and I can stream data to the LED array in real time, say stock exchange ticker.

Because it is from China it does not have any brand name, it's difficult to tell what sits inside.

Do you know - just looking at the app - what sits inside so that it is possible to create my own (real time streaming) drivers?

[image]

I think I'll have to dismantle it and check what is inside but maybe you'll know...

Comment: Absolutely no way for anyone to provide any assistance based on the Non-existent information that you have provided. Sorry.

Comment: include a link to the device ... add it to your question above

Comment: download the android app (LED Space) ...... also download java viewer app .... https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njlabs.showjava ..... use the java viewer app to decompile the LED Space app ..... use the JaDX decompiler because it seems to produce the most code .....  examine the resulting code ..... start with `com.yskj.led\java\com\yskj\rn\YsUdpLib.java` file

Comment: the screen appears to be related to this website .... http://www.popled.cn/About

Comment: this may be an example of the datafile .... http://a.popled.cn/Public/Upload/1544598549.json

Comment: I definitely need to undo the seams. I was hoping that you know by any chance what that could be... (no worries, I'll do my homework)

Answer (score 1):

If you open the device up you will find a bunch of chips and will be no wiser as the device is software controlled.

Since it is already working over WiFi you should try and hack the protocol by eavesdropping on working messages. Something like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) would be a suitable tool but it will take you a day or two to get familiar with it. You would then start to send very simple patterns such as one pixel, top-left, etc., to try to figure out the protocol. At the very least you should be able to duplicate a captured message sent from the app and try transmitting it from the Pi and see if it works. If it does then proceed with reverse engineering.